# Editing .htaccess file to modify URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to modify my .htaccess file to modify my URL and have tried many methods but cannot achieve exactly what I want. For example I have this URL:

```
http://mywebsite.com/FOLDER/index.php?id=5
```

Now I want it to look like:

```
http://mywebsite.com/FOLDER/5
```

or

```
http://mywebsite.com/FOLDER/ID/5
```

My .htaccess contains the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) index.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

I cannot figure out what's wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Your RewriteRule is reversed.  `RewriteRule <WHAT TO MATCH>  <WHAT TO REPLACE IT WITH>`.   Switch your two arguments.  The `$1` goes in the second argument, the pattern matching in the first one.  And careful, your path does not start with index (^index), it starts with "/FOLDER/index..."

Comment: @Nic3500 Okay so I've switch both of them and it looks like `RewriteRule index.php?id=$1 ^index/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) [NC]` now. Is it still wrong?  Because it's still not working. And my .htaccess file is in the \FOLDER and not root. Is that a problem?

Comment: No, the order was correct to begin with. But why are you trying to match URLs starting with `index/` - where exactly do you see that in `http://mywebsite.com/FOLDER/5` or `http://mywebsite.com/FOLDER/ID/5` …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+FOLDER/index\.php\?id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /FOLDER/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^FOLDER/(\d+)/?$ FOLDER/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Not working :( When I try to goto `FOLDER/5` it shows me `Not Found` message. Not sure what's wrong. I copy pasted your answer and my .htaccess is in the root of the website. Just a side note: I'm working on localhost if that's the problem?

Comment: Hey man, just letting you know but it worked! I don't know what was wrong before but now everything's working perfectly. Thanks alot!

Comment: is there documentation anywhere that i can learn how to rewrite the htaccess file? currently my primary domain is located at `public_html/primary_domain/`, but the issue with this is that when i redirect users from primarydomain.com to other pages (i.e. anotherpage.php), the url shows up as primarydomain.com/primarydomain/anotherpage.php

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `RewriteRule` is what the incoming url without domain and without preceding paths (more on that later) is going to be matched against. This url is, in your case, `http://mywebsite.com/FOLDER/5`. Assuming that your `.htaccess` file is in your DocumentRoot, the regex will match against `FOLDER/5`.

You are currently trying to match `FOLDER/5` with `^index/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)`, which is not going to work. A better regex would be `^(.*)/([0-9]+)$` or `^(.*)/ID/([0-9]+)$`. You can then rewrite to `$1/index.php?id=$2`. I would recommend using the `[L]` flag to stop rewriting for this round to avoid common problems with multiple rules matching while you do not expect them to.

---

Besides this, make sure that your `.htaccess` files are being read (e.g. by checking that if you enter garbage, you get a 500 internal server error), that mod_rewrite is enabled, that you are allowed to override `FileInfo`. You also may need to turn `AcceptPathInfo` off.

Comment: My .htaccess file is being read and I tried your method. The updated RewriteRule looks like `RewriteRule ^(.*)/ID/([0-9]+)$ $1/index.php?id=$2 [L]` now. Still not working. Any idea why?

Comment: I would need more information for that. Have you worked through the last paragraph? What did you find out?

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but I figured it out just now. Thanks for the reply!